# Get nested Childrens in JSON using Angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm working on json Data with inner childrens. i need to get all the name's in the json.

json data

```
this.res = [  
                  {
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "children": [],
                            "name": "P Sub Child 3",
                          },
                          {
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "children":[],
                                "name" : "data"
                              }
                            ],
                            "name": "PSubChild2",
                          }
                        ],
                      "name": "PChild1",
                      },
                      {
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "children": [],
                            "name": "PSubChild3",
                          }
                        ],
                        "name": "PChild2",
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": "Parent1",
                  },
                  {
                  "children": [],
                  "name": "Parent2",
                  }
    ];
```

in my application names of every child has to store in the variables using angular2.
Data is dynamic changes as per the user in my application

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4sj8RN?p=preview i found an example in angularjs but i want it in angular2

Comment: What have you tried so far? --- Also http://reactivex.io/learnrx/ will help you figure out this sort of thing on your own in the future.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i tried in many ways but can't get the inner childrens.

Comment: i guess the best way  to do it will be to make use of pipes which will give you the key for this response

Sample - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383720/angular2-getting-very-deep-nested-json-value-using-pipe-ngfor

Comment: @RahulSingh thanx for response. but i didn't get how to use pipes in angular2. if u provide any code that will help for me. and in my case data having childrens (nested childs) so length will vary.

Comment: You could make your own datatype, e.g `MyNode` which has children nodes (`Array<MyNodeNode> childen`) and a name attrbute (`nodeName:string`). Then you can create a method that recursively find all the names in your data-object.

Comment: @John can u please provide code for the about json so that it makes me more understable and helpful.

Comment: @NunnaS I added a possible implementation as an answer. Hope it works for you and that you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunkr of a possible implementation
https://plnkr.co/edit/njM1HLx7vuZY9loto2pM?p=preview

Create your own datatype:

```
export class MyNode {
  children:Array<MyNode>;
  name:string;
}
```

and then create a method to recursively loop your parents to get their names and the names of the children

```
parents:Array<MyNode> = [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [],
              "name": "P Sub Child 3",
            },
            {
              "children": [
                {
                  "children":[],
                  "name" : "data"
                }
              ],
              "name": "PSubChild2",
            }
          ],
          "name": "PChild1",
        },
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [],
              "name": "PSubChild3",
            }
          ],
          "name": "PChild2",
        }
      ],
      "name": "Parent1",
    },
    {
      "children": [],
      "name": "Parent2",
    }
  ];

 names:Array<string>=[];
 getAllNames(){
    this.getNameHelper(this.parents);
 }
 getNameHelper(parents:Array<MyNode>){
    for(var p of parents){
      if(p.name){
        this.names.push(p.name);
      }
      if(p.children){
        this.getNameHelper(p.children);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want to just get the value of the `name` property down the hierarchical data you have then as most here suggested you have to use recursion to get to the `name` property. With Rxjs it becomes a bit easier to do like following:

```
Observable.from(this.res)
.expand(d => d.children.length > 0 ? Observable.from(d.children) : Observable.empty())
.subscribe(d => console.log(d.name));
```

I have made a working sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimislam/ba17w8xz/1/